# Report Server: how to select everything if parameter = null or blank (allow multiple values is turned on)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

How to return everything in Report Server if parameter value is blank or null?

The solution:

```
SELECT some_column
FROM your_table
WHERE (@y is null or y >= @y)
```

Doesn't work in SSRS since "Allow null value" cannot be turned on, when parameter "Allow multiple values" is turned on.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways around this but the simplest is just to use the "Select All" option at appears at the top of multi-value parameter lists. If you need this to be the default then set the default and available value to the same query.

The "Select All" option is shown automatically for multi-value parameters when there is more than a single value in the list as shown here..

[image]

Other ways are similar, for instance you can add a value to the top of your parameter's available values list that has a label called "All" or something like that and a value you can look for in your query (e.g. -1).

BTW: Your sample code would not work with a multivalue parameter if used directly in the dataset query you would normally do something like

```
SELECT some_column
FROM your_table
WHERE (@y =-1 OR y IN(@y))
```

Comment: Alan, thank you very much for advice. I didn't find "Select All" option in parameter properties / general. Where can I find this? Concerning my code, everytime I try to compare @y with something (no matter what) it throws the error. Everything I do for now: 1) put query: where (y in (@y) or @y = '') 2) Define Query Parameters:  y = <blank> 3) report parameter properties: y = allow blank value('') - ok, allow multiple values - ok.

Comment: I've edited the answer to show the 'Select All; option. There is no property to turn this on/off, it's displayed automatically. Regarding the errors you get, you might want to start a new question on that. Make sure you include sample data and the datset queries you are using. Also show where the parameters's value and label fields are being set from

Comment: Alan, thank you for explanation. Select All is not quite exactly what I need, since I need that a List of values was copied into the cell. Select All requires to set by hands "check is ok" in front of every existing value. Since multiple value cannot be checked whether it is null or blank, I solved this by adding one more boolean parameter. If parameter is True then "Select ... where" if False then "Select without where". It is not slim but workable.

Comment: Ah OK, I didn't realise that you intended to populate the parameter values like that.

Answer (score 0):

This statement will return ALL rows in `your_table` if parameter is not provided. In SSRS, check the box for "Allow null value" for parameter `@y`.

```
DECLARE @y [data type] = NULL

SELECT some_column
FROM your_table
WHERE ((@y IS NULL)
        OR (some_column = @y))
```